# PHP Mysql Query Not able to grab each specific row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to grab the results of each row and print them out one at a time so that I can eventually place them in their own specific variables, but it isn't working.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  It just goes in an endless loop of printing out the first row.  I know there are 4 rows total.

```
$scores_query = mysql_query("SELECT Day, Time, AM_PM,
Away, 
case when Away_Score is null then '@' else Away_Score end as Away_Score, 
Home,
case when Home_Score is null then '' else Home_Score end as Home_Score
FROM `NFL_Games` WHERE Week=6 
order by
(case Day
 when 'Thu' then 1
 when 'Sat' then 2
 when 'Sun' then 3
 when 'Mon' then 4
 else 5 end), 
 Day, Time ASC");
 $count = mysql_num_rows($scores_query);
 echo "Hellloooo" . $count;
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($scores_query)) {
  for($x = 1; $x <= $count; $x++) {
    /*echo $results['Day'] . "__" . $results['Time'] . "__" . $results['AM_PM'] . "__" . $results['Away'] . "__" . $results['Away_Score'] . "__" . $results['Home'] . "__" . $results['Home_Score'];
    echo "<br/>";*/
    /*echo (Day, Time, AM_PM, Away, Away_Score, Home, Home_Score);*/
    if ($x = 1) {
    echo $results['Day'] . "__" . $results['Time'] . "__" . $results['AM_PM'] . "__" . $results['Away'] . "__" . $results['Away_Score'] . "__" . $results['Home'] . "__" . $results['Home_Score'];
    echo "<br/>";
    } else if ($x = 2) {
    echo $results['Day'] . "__" . $results['Time'] . "__" . $results['AM_PM'] . "__" . $results['Away'] . "__" . $results['Away_Score'] . "__" . $results['Home'] . "__" . $results['Home_Score'];
    echo "<br/>";
    } else if ($x = 3) {
    echo $results['Day'] . "__" . $results['Time'] . "__" . $results['AM_PM'] . "__" . $results['Away'] . "__" . $results['Away_Score'] . "__" . $results['Home'] . "__" . $results['Home_Score'];
    echo "<br/>";
    } else if ($x = 4) {
    echo $results['Day'] . "__" . $results['Time'] . "__" . $results['AM_PM'] . "__" . $results['Away'] . "__" . $results['Away_Score'] . "__" . $results['Home'] . "__" . $results['Home_Score'];
    echo "<br/>";
    } else {
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `but it isn't working` implies?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your if clauses.
Do you really want to assign values to $x at your if clause ?

If not, write your if clauses at this way: if($x == 2)

Hope i have understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing a for loop inside your while loop? Since you have `if ($x = 1)`, `$x` will be set to 1 everytime the for loop is ran, so it will run infinitely, and will never go out of the for loop and run the while loop a 2~nth time.

Since you are not doing anything with the `$x` in your for loop, just do your while loop and it will iterate over all 4 rows

```
while($results = mysql_fetch_array($scores_query)) {
    echo $results['Day'] . "__" . $results['Time'] . "__" . $results['AM_PM'] . "__" . $results['Away'] . "__" . $results['Away_Score'] . "__" . $results['Home'] . "__" . $results['Home_Score'];
    echo "<br/>";
}
```